# Does Kotlin's sortedBy keeps order of equal values?

Tags: sorting, kotlin

Suppose I have a list of values defined with some arbitrary order.

```kotlin
val list = listOf("a", "aa", "b", "bb")
```

If I sort this list using `sortedBy` using some `Comparable` property of the values.

```kotlin
val sorted = list.sortedBy { it.length }
```

Will the original arbitrary order be preserved for values that compare as equal?

```kotlin
["a", "b", "aa", "bb"] // good
["b", "a", "aa", "bb"] // bad
["a", "b", "bb", "aa"] // bad
["b", "a", "bb", "aa"] // bad
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [per the official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html):

> The sort is stable. It means that equal elements preserve their order relative to each other after sorting.